# How to ignore inner entity property with MVC3?

Tags: c#, mapping, entity-framework-4.1

I have a `Member` entity with a complex type called `Address` with a complex type called `UsState` which has the following properties: `Id`, `Name` and `Iso`.

I need to map the Member Address's `UsState` to its DB table column. The problem is that `members` table only contains `State (VARCHAR)` column, so in order to perform the right mapping, I did this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Property(p => p.BillingAddress.State.Name).HasColumnName("State");
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Ignore(p => p.BillingAddress.State.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Ignore(p => p.BillingAddress.State.Iso);
```

But it appears that `Ignore` only accepts base property lambdas, so I received this:

```
The expression 'p => p.BillingAddress.State.IsoCode' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.
```

How can I resolve this issue? (preferably using `Ignore` method)

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sublcass of `UsState`

```
public class UsStateSpecific : UsState
{
}
```

Then change the type of the `State` property in `BillingAddress`'s type to `UsStateSpecific`.

```
public class Address 
{
...
public UsStateSpecific State
...
}
```

Now ignore all desired properties from complex type (or entity) `UsStateSpecific`. This will not affect your other `UsState` properties in other types.

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<UsStateSpecific>().Ignore(p => p.Id);   
modelBuilder.ComplexType<UsStateSpecific>().Ignore(p => p.Iso);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UsState>().Ignore(p => p.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<UsState>().Ignore(p => p.Iso);
```

and remove this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Ignore(p => p.BillingAddress.State.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Ignore(p => p.BillingAddress.State.Iso);
```

Comment: But if I use `modelBuilder.Entity<UsState>().Ignore(p => p.Id);` won't it affect all the other instances of `UsState`? I just want to ignore Member->Address->State->Id.